# console.log jquery element on chrome look strange

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

```
 [<h1>, prevObject: e.fn.e.init[1], context: #document, selector: "h1"]
```

How do i get result looks like above?

This is the command i use: `console.log($('h1'));`
Can anyone get result like me on chrome Version 23.0.1271.64 m ?

Comment: Why do you think that is strange? What do you expect?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552432/show-html-when-logging-jquery-object-in-chrome-dev-tools-console

Answer (score 3):

Of course, you are looking for the entire HTML element

Use `console.log($('h1').get(0));` to check properties

Or `console.log($('h1')[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at all the child properties of a jQuery object.

If you click on the **+** in firefox you will see the same properties.. (*plus all the inherited methods*)