# Show Elements when logging jQuery object in Chrome Dev Tools console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

It seems like something has changed lately with Chrome Dev Tools. Logging a jQuery object with `console.log` used to show the Element of the DOM node in the console. Something like this:

```
[<a href="#employees">Employees</a>]
```

Now it has changed to a clickable object like this:

```
[<a>, context: <a>]
```

Is there a way to go back to the old style of object logging or even a different method to call on `console`?

I'm currently using version `23.0.1271.64`. Not sure exactly which version brought the change.

Comment: Works for me. Which version?

Comment: Version 23.0.1271.64. I don't like these changes also. In addition context menu "reveal in elements panel" doesn't show.

Comment: My version is 23.0.1271.64 as well. It shows the DOM node with a small arrow beside it and ellipsis inside.

Comment: 1) Go to jquery.com 2) open console 3) type in `$('h2')` and `console.log($('h2'))`. That will show the difference.

Comment: Noticed this as well a few days ago; used to be much better to debug dynamic elements than what we have now.

Comment: I noticed this a few weeks back when the "inspector" suddenly changed it's syntax, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it back or why on earth they changed to something that's just impossible to grok compared to the previous version?

Comment: You have to manually run `console.log = inspect;` in the console before using `console.log` in code. But it's painful to do so every time...

Comment: I filed a bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=162570. Click on the star icon to vote and track it.

Comment: There's already similar bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161156

 This behavior is partially fixed in Chrome Canary now (context menu working, highlight on hover doesn't).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want console.log() to spit out the DOM element, you need to log the DOM element and not the jQuery object. The DOM element is always accessible as the 0th element of the jQuery selector. So, the way you would access the actual DOM element from a jQuery selector is like this:

```
   $("#someSingleDOMObjectSelector")[0]
```

And to get the DOM element to appear in the log the way you would like, you would do this:

```
   console.log($("#someSingleDOMObjectSelector")[0]);
```

And for jQuery selectors which contain/return multiple DOM elements, you could loop them, like this:

```
   $('.someMultipleDOMObjectSelector').each(function(){
           //console.log($(this)[0]); //or -->
           console.log(this);
   });
```

As to why Chrome's dev tools do this, I can only guess that it is done because it makes more sense to log a jQuery object as an object.

Comment: Why would you do `$(this)[0]` when that's identical to just using `this`?

Comment: To demonstrate usage of the 0th element ... You are correct. `this = $(this)[0]`

Comment: `.each(console.log)` will also give you the indexes, and is shorter.

Answer (score 7):

I've found this helpful:

```
console.log.apply(console, $("a"));
```

Also, if you run `console.log = inspect;` from inside the console, things will output the old way, but it doesn't work if you just do it from your code, it has to be from the console.

Comment: The trick with inspect doesn't seem to work for me but `console.log.apply(console, $("a"));` is nice.

Comment: @DavidTuite The `console.log=inspect` thing only works if you enter it directly into the console and only applies to logs triggered from the console afterwards. Not a great solution, generally.The `.apply(console,` thing is way more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This was broken by the Chrome developers in November 12 and hasn't been fixed as of Canary today.

Use https://github.com/pimvdb/jquery.chromelog to restore the previous behavior as a workaround.

The syntax is slightly different:

```
$('a').log()
```

But it's designed to mirror the old, working behavior of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question `console.dir( element )` ..?

**Update:**
Dont do this

```
console.dir( $("el") ); // Dont do this
```

But use:

```
console.dir( document.getElementById("el") ); // Do this
```

Comment: @darkajax You didnt interprete my answer the way I intended it ;)

Comment: No problem, but is the +1 functional? xD

Comment: That just logs something like this: `jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]`.

Comment: I went to jQuery.com and tried in the console `console.dir( document.getElementById("jq-siteContain"))` and it gave me what you wanted. It didnt give me the init function. Dont use $("#el") but use document.getElementById(el)

Comment: @EricG That's an Element, not a JQuery object (there's a difference).

Comment: @nailer I know, this fella wanted to read the DOM element in console. Mission accomplished no?

Comment: @Ericg: Sorry, but I'd say not accomplished. Obviously the parent asked to log a jQuery object, but rather than an HTMLElement. jQuery selectors support a different syntax than getElementById (querySelectorAll is closer, but not entirely the same) and may be multiple elements, rather than a single one.

Comment: @nailer I agree that it's debatable, but he asks in different ways, he says `used to show the Element of the DOM node in the console`, even the answer marked as correct gives the same result (=DOM elem). Also this answer might be useful to others, but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this won't be fixed in nearest future. Chrome Canary still have this issue.
I like new console behavior with objects preview, but I want an exception for jQuery objects.

You can "patch" `console.log` a little bit to make it display jQuery objects like before.
It's possible to "convert" jQuery objects to list of separate arguments. For example:

```
$('div');
```

In console could be displayed like:

```
console.log('[', div[0], div[1], ..., ']');
```

I wrote the script which will modify `console.log` arguments for jQuery objects only:

```
(function(){
    var arraySlice = Array.prototype.slice;
    var originalFunction = console.log;

    var replaceObject = function(sourceArray, objectIndex) {
        var currentObject = sourceArray[objectIndex];
        var spliceArguments = Array.prototype.slice.apply(currentObject);

        if(currentObject.length) {
            // add commas and brackets
            for(var i = spliceArguments.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                spliceArguments.splice(i, 0, ',');
            }
            spliceArguments.splice(0, 0, objectIndex, 1, '[');
            spliceArguments.splice(spliceArguments.length, 0, ']');

            // patch source array
            sourceArray.splice.apply(sourceArray, spliceArguments);
        } else {
            sourceArray.splice(objectIndex, 1, '[]');
        }
    };

    var fixFunction = function() {
    if(typeof jQuery === 'function' && jQuery.fn) {
        var newArgs = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
        for (var i = newArgs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(newArgs[i] instanceof jQuery) {
                replaceObject(newArgs, i);
            }
        }
        originalFunction.apply(console, newArgs);
    } else {
        originalFunction.apply(console, arguments);
    }
    };

    fixFunction.toString = function() {
        return originalFunction.toString();
    };

    console.log = fixFunction;
}())
```

Now you can include this script in your page to override console behavior, but this is not a good way to fix this issue, so I've wrapped this in [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-console-fix/jlmkkpkcgomkdpfhgjlpaaonhafnjgob) which will do this automatically for all pages.