# Chrome console.log behavior

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [console.log jquery element on chrome look strange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329849/console-log-jquery-element-on-chrome-look-strange)

Assuming plain jQuery `console.log( $('form') )` example.

A month before or so, Google Chrome console output was in format:

```
[
<form class=​"edit" data-subdomain=​"f661a0b98992">​…​</form>​
]
```

which I could expand, see children etc.

Lately the console.log outputs something like this:

```
[<form>, context: <form>]
```

Which is also an expandable object but it contains unnecesary information for me and I can't find the 'clean' HTML children structure. I want the 'old' format. Now, how do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [console.log jquery element on chrome look strange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329849/console-log-jquery-element-on-chrome-look-strange), [Show HTML when logging jQuery object in Chrome Dev Tools console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552432/show-html-when-logging-jquery-object-in-chrome-dev-tools-console)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
​console.log($('form')[0])​
```

Answer (score 3):

You're logging a jQuery object; there's a lot more there than just the element. If you want to see only the element, do the following:

```
console.log( $("form").get() ); // .get() returns an array of elements
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.get()` to convert the jQuery object into an array.

```
console.log($('form').get())
```

Or you can loop through and log each element:

```
$('form').each(function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```